# Calabash iOS not working: Symbol not found: _rb_str_new_static

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, calabash

I am getting the following when trying to run any calabash command

```
calabash-ios version
Ignoring gherkin-2.12.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gherkin --version 2.12.2
Ignoring json-1.8.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine json --version 1.8.3
Ignoring bigdecimal-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bigdecimal --version 1.2.7
Ignoring psych-2.0.15 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine psych --version 2.0.15
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.7.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.7.1
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_str_new_static
  Referenced from: /Users/yfares/.calabash/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _rb_str_new_static
  Referenced from: /Users/yfares/.calabash/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

it was all about changing to the system default ruby

I used this command

```
rvm use system
```